# Переменные структуры при ее создании конструктором заполнены нулями или мусором?

Tags: c++, структуры, переменные, инициализация

Все мы знаем, что если создать некую локальную переменную, например int a, в нее может попасть мусор и она не будет равна нулю, а может, например -2153245789. Когда мы создаем глобальные переменные, они всегда заполнены нулями или пустой строкой . А чем будут заполнены переменные (ниже из примера массив next, counter, children, isTerminal), если мы создаём их локально, изменится ли что то? Надо ли в конструкторе идти по массивам, переменным и присваивать значение 0, или всё таки оно инициализируется само?

```
const int E_SIZE = 26;
struct node {
    int next[E_SIZE];
    bool isTerminal;
    int children;
    int counter[E_SIZE];
    node () {

    }
};


int main() {
    //...
    vector <node> a;
    a.push_back(node());
    // a[0] теперь имеет два массива заполненные нулями, children = 0, isTerminal = false, или может попасть мусор?
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем варианте - в полях класса мусор.

Если убрать конструктор `node () {}` (либо заменить его на `node() = default;`, но обязательно в теле класса, а не снаружи), то `node()` будет заполнять поля нулями (так же как и `node{}`, и `node переменная{};`). А вот `node переменная;` будет оставлять в полях мусор.

См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization